Copilot Studio SQL connector
I am trying to create a AI Agent in Copilot Studio just to understand what it is capable of.  I want to connect it up to a Azure SQL DB so I can ask it questions such as "How many orders have been made today" and it return me a figure such as 42.  However, I have connected to my Azure SQL database and selected a few tables to include which has this data, however, when asking it such a question it returns me a (correct) SQL query to run to get the data rather than running the query internally itself and presenting me a number of orders.  I have also added some synonyms to columns to cater for different variations of the same question however I only ever get a SQL query to run.
Anyone got any experience with this and know how to get the AI Agent to return data from a database rather than just queries to run on a database?
Thanks.
